# How does one catch errors with setAttributeNS() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, setattribute

If the variable sPoints string is *not* formatted correctly (eg, points are separated by a ';') the polygon doesn't draw and in the debugger I can see that an error was detected. However no exception is thrown that can be caught.
Works fine if:

`var sPoints = "310,320 400,320 379,358";`

but 'errors out' if:

```
var sPoints = "310,320;400,320;379,358";

 try {
    var NewPoly = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
    NewPoly.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', "someId");
    NewPoly.setAttributeNS(null, 'points', sPoints);
    NewPoly.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', myClass);
    NewPoly.setAttributeNS(null, 'onclick', "handlePgonClick(evt)");
    objSvgElem.appendChild(NewPoly);
  }
  catch (err) {
    vShowMsg("drawing shape failure: " + err.message);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could count how many points that the SVG DOM has accepted and compare that with the number you think you should get.

```js
var NewPoly = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "polygon");
NewPoly.setAttribute('points', "310,320;400,320;379,358");
alert(NewPoly.points.numberOfItems);

NewPoly.setAttribute('points', "310,320 400,320 379,358");
alert(NewPoly.points.numberOfItems);
```